# Is it possible to put a component inside a component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-component

I have made a `Form` component which I want to reuse, I have also made an `Submit` component which I want to reuse. Is it possible that I put the `Submit` component inside the `Form` component?

```
export const Form = () => {
    return (
        <form>
            
        </form>
    )
}
```

Submit.js

```
export const Submit = () => {
    return (
        <>
           <input type="submit">
        </>
    )
}
```

Quiz.js

```
export const Quiz = () => {
    return (
        <Form>
            <Submit>
        </Form>
    )
}
```

Comment: YES. Are you facing any issue in implementing the above structure ?

Comment: [This is a fundamental idea behind react.](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment) Make sure that you are importing the components https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/. Please may you update the question with the issue that you are facing?

Comment: You should always close tags in jsx `<Submit />`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need add argument 'props' to form component and output on display {props.children}:

```
const Form = (props) => {
  return (
      <form>
          {props.children}
      </form>
  )
}
```

[CodeSanbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-sara-yhjs8?file=/src/App.js:158-254)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`children` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment) to achieve this.

Basically, in your Form.js, use `props.children`

```
export const Form = (props) => {
    return (
        <form>
            {props.children}
        </form>
    )
}
```

Then in your `Quiz.js`, use it like this.

```
export const Quiz = () => {
    return (
        <Form>
           <Submit />
        </Form>
    )
}
```

The `<Submit />` component will now be rendered inside your `Form` component

Comment: Is this how I should use components?

Comment: Isn't is `props.children`? https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment

Comment: I think you meant `props.children` not `props.child`